# How a pointer initialization C statement in global space gets its assigned value during compile/link time?

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-construction, linker

The background of this question is to understand how the compiler/linker deals with the pointers when it is initialized in global space.

For e.g.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int a = 8;
int *p = &a;
int main(void) {
  printf("Address of 'a' = %x", p);
  return 0;
}
```

Executing the above code prints the exact address for `a`. 
My question here is, during at which process (compile? or linker?) the pointer `p` gets address of `a` ? It would be nice if your explanation includes equivalent Assembly code of the above program and how the compiler and linker deals with pointer assignment `int *p = &a;` in global space.

P.S: I could find lot of examples when the pointer is declared and initialized in local scope but hardly for global space.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: nitpick, don't use `"%x"` to print pointers. `"%p"` is the correct format for that, and you'd have to cast to `void*` before printing.

Comment: After googling, I came to know that 'Address binding' is the topic where the concept behind my doubts are explained. Could some one recommend me a good book (embedded system/RTOS oriented) in which this topic is explained well? - Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A module is linked (often named crt0.o) along with your program code, which is responsible for setting up the environment for a C program. There will be global and static variables initialized which is executed before `main` is called.

The actual address of the global variables are determined by the operating system, when it loads an executable and performs the necessary relocations so that the new process can be executed.

Comment: Thanks. (To be more clear) Then what's the reason a global variable can't be initialized with another variable? e.g: `int b =a;` restricted by the compiler in global space. It could be initialized in the same way you have mentioned.

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: If you mean the intialization of the global variables using another global variable, then this is prohibited by the C standard. Only in C++ you can do this.

Comment: Yes. Let me put my understanding from your answer: 1) The executable (in the .text area) will only have notation that `p` points to address of `a`. 2) The address of `a` is know at linker stage. 3) The C environment setup program at init time stores the address of `a` into  `p` . And Thus `int *p = &a` statement gets fulfilled.

Answer (score 1):

To run a program, the system has to load it into RAM. So it creates one huge memory block containing the actual compiled instructions. This block usually also contains a "data section" which contains strings etc. If you declare a global variable, what compilers usually do is reserve space for that variable in such a data section (there's usually several, non-writable ones for strings, and writable ones for globals etc.).

Whenever you reference the global, it just records the offset from the current instruction to that global. So an instruction can just calculate [current instruction address] + [offset] to get at the global, wherever it ended up being loaded. Since space in the data section has been reserved in the file anyway, they can write any (constant) value in there you want, and it will get loaded with the rest of the code.

This is how it works in C, and is why C only allows constants. C++ works like Devolus wrote, where there is extra code that is run before main(). Effectively they rename the main function and give you a function that does the setup, then calls your main function. This allows C++ to call constructors.

There are also some optimizations like, if a global is initialized to zero, it usually just gets an offset in a "zero" section that doesn't exist in the file. The file just says: "After this code, I want 64 bytes of zeroes". That way, your file doesn't waste space on disk with hundreds of "empty" bytes.

It gets a tad more complicated if you have dynamically loaded libraries (dylibs or DLLs), where you have two segments loaded into separate memory blocks. Since neither knows where in RAM the other one ended up, the executable file contains a list of name -> offset mappings. When you load a library, the loader looks up the symbol in the (already loaded) other library and calculates the actual address at which e.g. the global is at, before main() is called (and before any of the constructors run).

Comment: Thanks for the explaining the concept. Though I'm bit aware of the basics you have explained, I was unclear on pointers initialization (how the initial value got assigned to it), that why I posted this question.